# What is the difference between Type** name, and Type* name[]?

Tags: c++, c

What is the difference between Type** name, and Type* name[]?

Why would someone use one over the other?

Thanks

Comment: There is no difference, effectively. For example, we always see char **argv and char *argv[] used interchangeably to declare arguments to main in a C program. You might choose one over the other for reasons of clarity or consistency.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well that depends, is it in a variable declaration or in a function argument? If in a variable declaration:

```
Type** name = &pointer_to_type;
Type* name[] = { &pointer_to_type, 0, &pointer_to_type };
```

The first one is a pointer to pointer to type, while the second one is an array of pointers to type of length 3.

If in a function argument, they are the same thing. Arrays decay to pointers, and both `Type** name` and `Type* name[]` are exactly the same as function arguments. However, the second form makes it clear that name is an array of pointers of unknown length, while the first one does not. I would use `Type**` to specify a single element and `Type*[]` to specify an array.

Comment: I'm scared of you, little horse. Member for 32 days and 6000 of reputation. What's the technique?

Comment: Like to add a bit about memory allocation, too:  Using `Type* name[]` as a variable declaration automatically gets you valid memory at the first dereference (array of pointers is laid out on the stack).  You could use these commands in sequence: `Type* name[4]; name[3] = NULL;`  But if you tried that with `Type** name`, you'd segfault unless you manually made it point to a valid `Type*`.

Comment: @sidyll: Enthusiasm I'd guess? I even have a badge for that :P

Comment: Well, and I have a Fanatic badge :-) Anyway, congratulations for your effort and talent in answering with precision.

Comment: K-Ballo: Y U NO GIVE BOUNTIES??

Comment: @sidyll, thanks for a laugh... I too couldn't help noticing that little horse is on fire. @K, here's another badge for you!

Answer (score 4):

The difference between the two is mostly demonstrated when declaring/defining objects of either type.

The notation `Type *name[]` creates an array of unknown size (can be inferred from the initializer), `Type** name` creates a pointer. That means:

```
char *array[]={"hello", "world", 0}; /* OK, array of size 3 */
char **ptr={"hello", "world", 0};    /* not possible */
```

They behave differently in some expressions. Particularly, arrays can't be assigned to, but pointer variables can:

```
ptr++, ptr=array; /* assignment and mutation of ptr possible */
// array=whatever /* impossible */
```

The sizeof operator works differently on the two. `sizeof(array)` will depend on the number of elements of the array (may be 12 in this case), but `sizeof(ptr)` returns always the same size (eg. 4 on main 32-bit architectures)

Also, when declaring global variables, you mustn't mix the two:

```
extern char* data[];
```

must be accompanied in the `.c` file by

```
char* data[N];
```

and vice versa. Basically, defining the array means allocating several consecutive objects, whereas defining a pointer means allocating a single variable. The compiler treats both differently, and must know which is which.

However, when declaring or passing parameters to functions, they are the same. So

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) /* the same */
```

Comment: "_arrays are not lvalues_" They **are** lvalues. "_so they can't be assigned to_" And it would not follow anyway: (x is not an lvalue) does **not** imply ("x = whatever;" is ill-formed). C++ is not a simple language. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context.

If it defines a variable which is not a function parameter, then
in `Type** name`, `name` is a pointer to a pointer to a variable of type `Type` and in `Type* name[SOME_POSITIVE_INTEGER_CONSTANT]`, it's an array of pointers to variables of type `Type`.

If it's a function parameter, then both are the same, and `name` is a pointer to a pointer to a variable of type `Type`.

Comment: In a variable **declaration** that is **not** a definition, you can omit `SOME_POSITIVE_INTEGER_CONSTANT`

Comment: @curiousguy: at file scope "int* ga[];" results in "warning: array `ga' assumed to have one element". In function scope "int* ma[];" results in "error: array size missing in `ma'". You want to avoid such situations. "extern int* ega[];" is OK, however. This is with gcc (3.3.4), compiled as C with all warnings enabled.

Comment: There is no such thing as "file scope". You probably mean global scope. In any scope, a variable declaration without the storage class qualifier `extern` is also a **definition**.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Type** is a pointer to pointer. Think it like (Type*)* . So it points to Type* which can be a Type or Type[].

And the other one, Type* is a pointer to a Type or in this case, an array Type[]. So they are 'almost' the same.

Comment: Please don't think of it as `(Type*)*`! The grammar doesn't work that way. Think of it as `Type *(*)`, or rather `Type (*(*name))`: the expression `(*(*name))` is of type `Type`. (But it doesn't work for references, or functions.)